# How to safely root Samsung Galaxy Core Prime?

Tags: rooting, unbricking, samsung-galaxy-core-prime

In a nut shell I would like to safely root my Samsung Galaxy Core Prime or install another capable custom OS, because I really am unimpressed to the point I may return to T-mobile for the $30 LG Leon.

Last time I tried, I bricked it and had to swap for new one but they run like crap without root access.

I have rooted a few I am also trying to learn about coding and building Android apps... but I really just need help figuring out how to fix a soft bricked Android and/or how to save my info to SD  before I root so that I can get it back.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you search on Google on [how to safely root your device](https://www.google.com/search?q=How+to+root+Samsung+Galaxy+Core+Prime%3F&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8).  You should choose the one that is appropriate for your device (it should have the same [model number](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HxbqrWrrNtg)).

Also, install a Custom Recovery ([CWM](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Va4WNcMHRPk) or [TWRP](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7pixNnLvK-Y)) and please do a [NANDROID Backup](http://trendblog.net/android-guide-make-nandroid-backup-android-phone/) first, so you can easily restore your phone if something bad happens ...

---

### UPDATE:

> **Disclaimer**:  I am not responsible for rooting your Android device in any way.  Before performing any of these steps make sure you back up your Android device completely ...
>
> Please proceed at your own risk!

There are a number of ways on how to root a specific device, so you should know your Model Number, because they vary on the Model Number.

#### Model Number

To find your model number, (I'm assuming that your device is Android [4.4-kitkat](/questions/tagged/4.4-kitkat)):

1. Open Settings, scroll down and tap on About Phone.
2. The Model Number should be there.

#### Custom Recovery

Your phone must be rooted, in order to install a Custom Recovery.

To install a Custom Recovery:

1. Enable `USB Debugging` on your phone:

   - Open Settings, scroll down, and tap on About Phone.
   - Tap on the Build Number 7 times.
   - Go back to the Main Settings Screen, and tap on Developer Options.
   - Scroll down, and find USB Debugging.  Enable it.
2. Download the recovery you want for your device ([CWM](http://androidhost.org/hUhuh) or [TWRP](http://androidhost.org/IA98D))

   - The recovery that you will download should be compatible with your device.
3. Download and install [Odin](http://odindownload.com/SamsungOdin/#.WBhsHRJLARI) on your computer, as well as [USB Drivers](http://odindownload.com/SamsungUSBDriver/USB_Drivers_1.5.27.0.rar).
4. Extract the downloaded recovery file.
5. On your Android device, go to Download Mode.

   - I suggest that you search on Google on [how to boot into Download Mode on your specific device](http://www.google.com/search?q=How+to+boot+into+Download+Mode+on+Samsung+Galaxy+Core+Prime&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8), but usually, the combination is this:

     - Power off your phone.
     - Hold <kbd>Volume Down</kbd>, <kbd>Home</kbd>, and <kbd>Power</kbd> buttons at the same time.
     - Press <kbd>Volume Up</kbd> to continue.
6. Connect your device to your computer, and make sure it detects your device.
7. On Odin, tap `AP` and locate the extracted recovery file.
8. Click `Start`.
9. Just wait a minute or less, and the Custom Recovery should be installed on your device.

   **NOTE**: *To check if the Custom Recovery is successfully installed, go to Recovery Mode:*

   - Power off your phone.
   - Hold <kbd>Volume Up</kbd>, <kbd>Home</kbd>, and <kbd>Power</kbd> Buttons at the same time.
   - Release your fingers on the buttons when the Manufacturer Logo (the first screen that appears during boot, usually Samsung ...) appears.

#### NANDROID Backup

To perform a [nandroid](/questions/tagged/nandroid) Backup of your phone, you must have a Custom Recovery installed on your phone (which you have done earlier).

- Boot into Recovery Mode.
- Go to Backup and Restore for CWM, or Backup for TWRP.
- Follow the instructions on how to make a NANDROID Backup of your phone.

  - Usually, you only need to backup `System`, `Data`, and `Boot`.  But, it's up to you if you want to backup all partitions, as long as you have enough Storage Space.

Comment: I believe it would be better if you listed down an appropriate method of rooting the device rather than just telling the user 'I suggest you search on google'. That's like someone asking how to take screenshot without buttons and you telling them search on google...

Comment: Also offer a brief build up of the link attached as links can expire or change over time for users who'll visit this question in the future.

Comment: I'm sorry, if my answer only includes links that may change anytime.

Comment: I already updated my answer ...

Comment: To down voters:  How can I improve my answer? ...

Comment: Actually I think whoever down voted did so before your answer was updated. I'd always include a brief summary of what you're attaching in a link next time.